# Xcode builds Mac app, but doesn't run the app

Tags: xcode, macos, build, xcode5

I'm using Xcode 5.0.2 and when I try to Build and Run my Mac OS app, the Build completes properly and the Run stops as soon as it starts. When I start the Build+Run, I see a new Build entry in the Log Navigator. It completes nicely:

[image: Build Log]

Then another "Debug" Run entry shows up in the Log Navigator, but That log remains empty and then Stop button becomes disabled.

[image: Run Log]

I've looked through other SO posts which have the same problem. I've tried their other solutions, but they haven't worked for me. The things I've tried include:

- Restarting Xcode
- Changing the Architectures to only 64 bit
- Deleting the Run scheme and regenerating
- Ensuring the Run scheme has my App set as the executable
- Ensuring the Run scheme debugger is set to LLDB

[image]

Comment: It was provisions problem in my case.